# How Parent Taxonomy automatically added to the post when using `wp_set_object_terms()`?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I uses `wp_set_object_terms()` to add taxonomy to posts.

Assume that I have following taxonomy.

Topic Taxonomy

Parent Tax : Mobile Phones(id=10)
Child Tax : Samsung (id =12)

When I am using `wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, '12' , 'topic', true );` only "Samsung" is added to that post.

I need automatically add "Mobile Phones" to that post because "Mobile Phones" is parent tax for Samsung tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_ancestors()` to get parents and grandparents etc. of a term, then use that in `wp_set_object_terms()`:

```
$term_id = 12;
// Get array of term parents.
$terms = get_ancestors( $term_id, 'topic' ); 
// Include original term in array.
$terms[] = $term_id; 
// Add parents and original term to post.
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, 'topic', true );
```